# Only doing whitespace-cleanup on the lines touched

Tags: whitespace-mode, version-control

For most projects I work on I use a `before-save-hook` to run `whitespace-cleanup`.  This is fine when everybody on the team cleanups up their spaces but sometimes I am involved in already running projects were most files are littered with trailing white.  Currently I simply turn off my save-hook and add my share of spaces but ideally I want my diffs to be squeaky clean..

Are there any packages out there which only cleanup whitespace on the lines I touched?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`ws-butler`](https://github.com/lewang/ws-butler) package removes whitespace only from the touched lines. The package is available on Melpa.

From that package's README on github:

> Only lines touched get trimmed. If the white space at end of buffer is changed, then blank lines at the end of buffer are truncated respecting require-final-newline.
>
> Trimming only happens when saving.

Comment: Ooh, I like this solution, I've had this same problem often.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across [`whitespace-cleanup-mode](https://github.com/purcell/whitespace-cleanup-mode), which, according to its Github page is

> a minor mode which calls `whitespace-cleanup` before saving the
>   current buffer, but only if the whitespace in the buffer was initially
>   clean.

It may not do exactly what you want, but it may help others with a similar problem.